# passing a string from a table view controller to a new view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, viewcontroller

objective-c and ios newbie here but I'm learning!

name is a string in descs. I'm trying to pass it to a new view controller through detailViewController.note. I can see in debugging that the string is being saved in detailViewController.note ,but when I go over to my other view controller it is not there.

here is the code from my table view controller:

```
  -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

        DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc]init];
        detailViewController.view.frame=self.view.frame;
        detailViewController.title=@"detail";
        detailViewController.note=[self.descs[indexPath.row]name];
        [[self navigationController] pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];


    }
```

Header for DetailViewController:

```
@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic) NSString * note;
@end
```

Implementation for DetailViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UITextView *description =[[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12,260,300,180)];
    description.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15];
    description.editable=NO;
    description.text=self.note;
    [self.view addSubview:description];
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set up your subview in `viewWillAppear:`. It's not working in your current implementation because `viewDidLoad` is called before `detailViewController.note` has been set.